# Zend Youtube API getTotalUploadViews() not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

i'm having an issue trying to pull the total upload views from a user's profile. Here's the script i have at the moment. It all works fine, until i try to pull `getTotalUploadViews()`.

Anyone know how i can resolve this?

```
global $yt;
// set protocol version to 2 to retrieve a v2 profile entry,
// which contains additional information from the user's profile
$yt->setMajorProtocolVersion(2);
// enter a username or set the $userName variable to 'default'
// to retrieve the currently authenticated user's profile
$userProfileEntry = $yt->getUserProfile($userName);
 echo "<h3>Profile Information</h3><br />";
$userInfo = $userProfileEntry->getUsername();
 echo '<span><a href="http://youtube.com/user/'.$userInfo.'"><h4><img src="img/youtube.jpg" style="height:20px;width:20px;" /> '.$userInfo.'</h4></a></span><br />';
$proImage = $userProfileEntry->getThumbnail()->getUrl();
 echo '<img src="'.$proImage.'" style="height:150px;" class="img-polaroid"/><br />';
 echo '<hr>';


// retrieve counts of favorites, contacts, subscriptions and uploads
// by examining the feedLink elements in the profile
$statistics = $userProfileEntry->getStatistics();
 echo '<br /><br />';
 echo 
  '
    <div class="tabbable tabs-left" id="info-tabs">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#bi" data-toggle="tab">Member Info</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#vi" data-toggle="tab">Channel Statistics</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#oi" data-toggle="tab">Other Info</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="tabed-info">
      <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="bi">
      <p>
        <strong>Member Since: '.$userProfileEntry->getPublished()->text.'</strong><br />
        <strong>Last Update: '.$userProfileEntry->getUpdated()->text.'</strong>
      </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="vi">
        <p>
          <strong>Favorite Videos: '.$userProfileEntry->getFeedLink('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.favorites')->countHint.'</strong><br />
          <strong>User Contacts: '.$userProfileEntry->getFeedLink('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.contacts')->countHint .'</strong><br />
          <strong>Subscriptions: '.$userProfileEntry->getFeedLink('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.subscriptions')->countHint.'</strong><br />
          <strong>Video Uploads: '.$userProfileEntry->getFeedLink('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.uploads')->countHint.'</strong><br />
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="oi">
        <p>
          <strong>Channel Views: '.$statistics->getViewCount().'</strong><br />
          <strong>Videos Watched: '.$statistics->getVideoWatchCount().'</strong><br />
          <strong>Subscribers Count: '.$statistics->getSubscriberCount().'</strong><br />
          <strong>Test: '.$statistics->getTotalUploadViews().'</strong>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  ';
```

After i attempt to echo `<strong>'.$statistics->getTotalUploadViews().'</strong>` the page only half loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getTotalUploadViews() is not a method of the Zend_Gdata_YouTube_Extension_Statistics class.

Where did you see that method name?

### Updated:

It looks like that's an attribute provided by YouTube, but not explicitly handled by the Zend Statistics class. However - it looks like the Zend class saves any unrecognized attributes to a generic "extensionAttributes" array.

Try calling `$statistics->getExtensionAttributes()` and see if the value you need is included in the return value from that.

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($statistics->getExtensionAttributes()); ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: Straight from here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:statistics

Comment: Is there a method that i can use which will do the same?